# PDF creation using iTextsharp taking too much of time

Tags: asp.net, itext

Iam using ASP.Net along with iTextsharp to generate PDF files. Data is returned from SQL Server in to ASP.Net in the form of a DataTable. For example if my datatable contains 1000 records with varying company id and branch id, my requirement is to write PDFs grouped by companyid and branch id.

```
CompanyID     Code    Name   BranchId   Amount
1             XXXX    xxx      10        XXXX
1             XXXX    xxx      20        XXXX
5             XXXX    xxx      20        XXXX
1             XXXX    xxx      10        XXXX
1             XXXX    xxx      10        XXXX
2             XXXX    xxx      30        XXXX
5             XXXX    xxx      30        XXXX
3             XXXX    xxx      20        XXXX
1             XXXX    xxx      50        XXXX
4             XXXX    xxx      20        XXXX
6             XXXX    xxx      20        XXXX
4             XXXX    xxx      10        XXXX
```

My main problem is that its taking too much time to generate PDFs. My logic is simple:

```
foreach companyId in distinct Companylist
    foreach branchid in companyId
      Populate data based on a HTML template
      Write the HTML output to PDF using iTextsharp
    loop
loop
```

Is there any better approach? For 200 records, it took 30minutes to generate the PDFs. How do I minimize the time. Please help.

Comment: I can create PDFs with thousands of records in less than a second straight from code. I can do the same with a little bit of overhead when I make a detour through HTML. All depends on how well you code. As you don't share your code, the only comment we can give is: change your design. If you can't change your design: improve your code.

Comment: I agree with Bruno, I've hundreds of pages in just a few seconds. But without code we can't really help you. However, there are three major things that you should time, the SQL portion, the HTML generation portion and the iText portion.

Comment: To back Bruno and Chris: Your "logic" seems to imply that you prepare each row of your table as a separate HTML input, setup a separate HTML processing pipeline, etc. In other words, that logic seems to push the meaning of *overhead* to an extreme...